# How to insert string list to listbox in matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have small question concerning gui in matlab.
I don't know exactly how to insert/apply list of string to listbox?
I don't want to specify fixed list of string in property inspector.

```
strList = {'aaaa', 'yes', 'no', 'maybe', 'sure'};
```

or

```
strList = ['aaaa', 'yes', 'no', 'maybe', 'sure'];
```

Answer (score 1):

a) **To add the item at the end** of your list (`strList = {'aaaa', 'yes', 'no', 'maybe', 'sure'};`):

```
strList{end+1} = 'add';
```

strList =

```
'aaaa'    'yes'    'no'    'maybe'    'sure'    'add'
```

b) **To insert the item** at, for example, `n=3`:

```
strList = [strList(1:n-1), 'insert', strList(n:end)];
```

strList =

```
'aaaa'    'yes'    'insert'    'no'    'maybe'    'sure'    'add'
```

To set the strings into the listbox:

```
hListBox = uicontrol('Style','List', 'String',strList);
set(hListBox, 'String', strList) 
% to get string from ListBox
strList = get(hListBox, 'String');
```

where `hListBox` is the handle for your listbox.